# How to insert row to excel table with column number in oledb?

Tags: c#, excel, oledb

I want to insert some rows to a no header excel table by oledb.  For example, insert to column A, B, C, and E column by the following query:

```
 Insert into [Sheet1$] (A,B,C,E) values('0','a','zz''2019-09-09')";
```

However, I got an error which Column A not found.

could anyone tell me how to insert rows to  a no header excel table?

```
 System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection MyConnection;
            System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand myCommand = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand();
            string sql = null;


            MyConnection = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='C:\excelFile.xlsx';Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;");
            myCommand.Connection = MyConnection;

             sql = "Insert into [Sheet1$] (A,B) values('0','a')";               

            myCommand.CommandText = sql;
            myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MyConnection.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding `HDR=No` to the extended properties of connection string like:

```
MyConnection = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='C:\excelFile.xlsx';Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;HDR=No");
```

HTH

Comment: It will bring a
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException (0x80004005): Could not find installable ISAM. error

Comment: @MRWonderFuXker try adding `;` after HDR=No, so that it looks like "...HDR=No;"

Comment: no, it didn't. I am finding another way to do this. :(

Comment: @MRWonderFuXker do you still get that 0x80004005 crash or some other error?

Comment: i still get the 0x80004005 error form the code..  the full error is about: `System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException (0x80004005): Could not find installable ISAM. at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionInternal.`

Comment: hi, after change my query syntax to   `MyConnection = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='C:\excelFile.xlsx;Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=NO';");` the 0x80004005 error is gone, but an error: 
`INSERT INTO statement contain
s the following unknown field name: 'A'. Make sure you have typed the name corre
ctly` still here

Answer (score 0):

after change the connection string to `MyConnection = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.O‌​LEDB.12.0;Data Source='C:\excelFile.xlsx;Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=NO';");` I have to modify the column which the query update to.

F1 means the first row and so on.

```
 sql = "Insert into [Sheet1$] (F1,F2) values('5','e')";
```